# Visual Studio 2010 SP1 won't install

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I have a **clean** install of 64-bit Windows 7 where I have installed VS 2010. All's well. Then I wanted to install VS 2010 Service Pack 1, but it won't install. There's no error, but the install goes on an on an on forever. It's on file SP1 Core "1 out of 15" forever, the progress bar doesn't move etc. I've let it run for two hours on two occasions.

What's going on? Help!

Pom

Comment: Just let it run. It took me close to 6 hours to install it on my machine and during most of that time it looked like it was stuck.

Comment: Also, it might be an idea to set up a temporary exclusion in your AV config to stop it painstakingly scanning every file that gets unpacked and updated. Norton in particular (but not exclusively)  is especially ... zealous when it comes to scanning big CABs which tickle lots of files in this type of scenario.

Comment: I've had the same problem.  What's worse is that when it's actually finished, the Web Standard update (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83), the original reason I attempted to install SP1, still complains that SP1 is missing.  What's weird is that I can set  the Visual Studio HTML validator to (X)HTML5, but then it complains that every tag (even the <html> tag!) is not recognized.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, it takes a long time to install SP1. I had to do the following steps because it kept crashing after about 1 hour.

1. Download SP1
2. Disconnect from Network / turn off Wireless
3. If your happy to trust the download turn off Virus Protection during install.
4. Disable UAC while installing, They annoy the hell out of me anyway so I leave them off all    the time. type UAC into the start menu and press enter, move the slider to the bottom. If you can't do this try option C as shown in the following article: http://www.petri.co.il/disable-uac-in-windows-7.htm
5. Run install leave it run for a couple of hours, ( it does take a while)

Comment: This basically worked for me when I had problems installing SP1 on W8.1. Specifically I downloaded the 1.4GB iso, mounted it and then ran setup.exe as administrator. I didn't bother with the other stuff. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This is what i did from **Program and Features**:

1. Try to uninstall WCF RIA Services, but it took too long, so I stoped it using task manager
2. Repair WCF RIA Services
3. Install the VS2010 SP1 and it completed successfully.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
You have to set HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\msiserver\WOW64 to DWORD(0) to run the SP1 installer on Win7 x64.